# Continuous integration / Cruisecontrol advice

Tags: continuous-integration, cruisecontrol, cruisecontrol.rb

I've been tasked with setting up a continuous integration server for our project and am weighing up the options.

I would like to use cc.rb rather than cc for the simple fact that I'd rather be writing Ruby than XML. From what I can see cc is a more mature product and comes with more features out of the box.

So I would like to know if you were setting up an integration server with the following requirements, which system would you choose and how would you go about it?

- Mercurial support
- Run selenium test suite on multiple platforms
- x10 support for build lights (not essential)

Any guidance would be appreciated.

Regards,

Chris

Answer (score 3, accepted):

yup I agree, hudson is much more easier to manage and has a variety of nifty plugins that make it flexible

It does have mercurial support
http://wiki.hudson-ci.org/display/HUDSON/Mercurial+Plugin

Selenium support is also available
http://thinkvitamin.com/dev/easy-automated-web-application-testing-with-hudson-and-selenium/

Answer (score 1):

Have you considered using hudson. It has support for multiple languages and pluins and it generally very flexible.

I believe it has mercurial support and you could prob hook in selenium test somehow.

Karl

Answer (score 1):

Well personally I would use the original CruiseControl, but that's probably because I helped write it.  ;)

There are lots of tools available to do what you want (CC, cc.rb, Hudson, etc.).  If you just care about running those tests then most of them will do. If you want a more polished experience and a few more features (like IDE integration) then tools like Zutubi Pulse (or Bamboo or Team City) start to look good.  If you want to get into the full lifecycle (CI->test->deployment) and reporting from multiple tools then something higher end like AnthillPro might be the way to go.

So really a question of what else you think you might want to do.

Comment: The other things that I would like to do it run Rake scripts and build some Rails projects.